# Missing slash in dynamic link

Tags: firebase, flutter

I've been working with firebase/flutter for about half a year, so I'm still pretty green, and this is . I'm trying to use firebase's **sendSignInWithEmailLink**. I do get the mail with the link, but the link doesn't work. Looking deeper into the link, the problem is, that it is missing a slash:

[https://example.page.link?link=https:/example-development.[...]](https://example.page.link?link=https:/example-development.%5B...%5D)

----------------------------------------^

When I manually insert the slash and post it in a browser, I get the right result (open app with link).

I've been looking around for solutions, and similar topics have been around for a couple of years, but it doesn't seem like there's a solution for it, except that it's a problem in firebase (need to wait for them to solve it).

The question is - are there others, who stumble upon this problem, and what should I do from here?

```
_auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
    email: emailController.text,
    actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
        url: 'https://example.page.link/link',
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        androidPackageName: 'com.example',
        iOSBundleId: 'com.example',
    )
)
```

/Andique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could simply be the strange behavior of the email client that you open that email in. If you look at [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/5054) posted on Firebase GitHub repo, the author of the issue solved this by using another email client.

Comment: I thought I had tested that, you're right - it is the mail client. But I still need to work around this problem somehow - I can't tell the customers that they need to use another mail client if they want to sign in.

Is there a way to work around it, or should I contact windows support and have them fix something?

Comment: I found this article about how to change it on your own computer, but I can't depend on customers doing this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/url-multiple-slashes-become-single-slash

Comment: You could perhaps in your Flutter application warn the user before sending the email link, perhaps show a dialog or a text message to the user telling them about this issue with this email client and ask them to open the email somewhere else

Comment: Seems like that must be it - or maybe ask the user to open it on a computer instead of android. Anyway, thanks for your help :-)